# Google analytics data, showing real time data but standard reporting shows nothing

Tags: web-services, google-analytics

Attempting to use GA to log traffic accessing some web services.
Code constructs a gif url and opens a connection to it.

While testing, I can open GA and see the traffic in real time reporting coming in.
Standard reporting however, shows nothing. I've waited several days just in case it "magically" appeared but no such luck. I have no filters acting on this profile.

I would think that any request getting to real time would be valid enough for standard reporting, but what other differences are there between the two that would cause this discrepancy aside from filters?

Comment: Can you show the gif url generated? It may be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Admin>Tracking Info and switch on Subdomains of your website.